# CLion doesn't resolve all macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, clion

I've 5 files (+ makefile):

- `hello_city.h`, `hello_world.h`, `hello_world.c`: These files depict
  a framework that is used within an application. It allows some
  configurations based on the needs of the application. Within the files `#if` and `#endif` is used to opt-in and -out source code that corresponds with certain options.
- `main.c`: represents the application
- `conf.h`: defines the configuration flags.

The `conf.h` is indirectly included via the `makefile`.

The problem is that CLion can resolv the macros defined in `conf.h` (via go to declaration) but it doesn't consider them for highlightning. Which means the parts with `#if` are always collapsed and highlighted as comments. You can see that behaviour within `hello_world.c`.

Is it possible to configure CLion in a way that it considers such declarations or at least to disable the collapsing and 'comment'-highlightning?
Keep in mind it is not possible to get rid of the `makefile` since it's a huge project with a complex setup. ([original source](https://github.com/daniel-wer/contiki/tree/secrdc-demos))

The source files for the simplified example can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Benedikt1992/05d01948ed1638e656b1dfbad244337c

**UPDATE:** simplification and clarification of the base problem

Comment: No, we're not going to trawl through your extensive source code to try to diagnose this for you.  If you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, however, then we will be pleased to discuss its nature, possible causes, and possible solutions.

Comment: I'll try to come up with a simpler example

Comment: @JohnBollinger included Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had just said this ...

> The conf.h is indirectly included via the makefile.

... in the first place, then we probably could have saved a lot of time.  To clarify what I'm talking about, however, since you forgot to put your MCVE directly into the question, here's the code showing what you seem to mean:

**hello_world.h**:

> ```
> #ifndef SAMPLE_HELLO_WORLD_H
> #define SAMPLE_HELLO_WORLD_H
>
> /* PROJECT_CONF_H might be defined in the project Makefile */
> #ifdef PROJECT_CONF_H
> #include PROJECT_CONF_H
> #endif /* PROJECT_CONF_H */
>
> void hello_world();
>
> #endif //SAMPLE_HELLO_WORLD_H
> ```

... where `PROJECT_CONF_H` is not defined anywhere in the sources, but rather via compiler command-line option specified in the Makefile.

Anyway, you ask:

> The problem is that CLion can resolv the macros defined in conf.h (via
>   go to declaration) but it doesn't consider them for highlightning.

I think you're trying to say that in files that include `hello_world.h`, CLion's code highlighting mechanisms do not recognize any of the declarations  (particularly macro definitions) from the file named, via the Makefile, by `PROJECT_CONF_H`.

> Which means the parts with #if are always collapsed and highlighted as
>   comments. You can see that behaviour within hello_world.c.
>
> Is it possible to configure CLion in a way that it considers such
>   declarations or at least to disable the collapsing and
>   'comment'-highlightning?

Although it's very likely that CLion can be configured to disable collapsing code sections that are suppressed by preprocessor conditionals, it's hard to blame this problem on CLion.  Very likely it is analyzing only your source files, not your Makefile, so as far as it is concerned, your configuration header is indeed never included.  It knows the header is *there*, so the symbols therein are in its index, but that's it.

I observe at this point that a code structure such as present is pretty unusual.  Specifically, build systems that provide build-time configuration data via a header file ordinarily ensure that the header is always present, with the same name, and operate by setting its *contents* as necessary in a pre-build configuration step (or by requiring a person to do that manually).

> Keep in mind it is not possible to get rid of
>   the makefile since it's a huge project with a complex setup.

`make` is a terrific tool.  There's no reason to want to dump `make` or the Makefile.  But you very well should consider changing how this aspect of it works.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Although it doesn't resolv the 'problem' directly it gives a broad understanding of the underlying issue and hints on how to handle it.